# SQL Server : dynamic procedure/pivot not working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

This isn't my code, it's my predecessor's. I'm trying to tidy a lot of stuff up. This is just one of many procedures that isn't doing what i want it to. I don't want to rewrite half of the mess that was created so any help with making it pretty will be appreciated. I have had to redact some table names but they aren't important

There are two procedures, one to insert into a table and one to create a view. The insert works correctly but the view doesn't work when the data in @cols doesn't contain text at the beginning of the year. So, if i have T_2020 it will work correctly but if i have just 2022 i get a syntax error.  the data in @cols is created from this line:

select Census_Year = ('Yr_' + sp.Census_Year_Convert)

which is in the insert procedure

if i remove the 'Yr_' i get a syntax error. ive tried making sure every census_year value is all the same type and it still doesnt work

The output i want is a pivot table with years in each column along with the school type and FTE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE insert


AS 

--error handling statements
BEGIN -- Procedure Code
    Declare -- declare variable for error reporting values
        @RC INT = 0;
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Clear Table Data

TRUNCATE TABLE a;

;
with 

sp as (

SELECT Census_Year_Convert = convert(nvarchar(16), [CENSUS_YEAR])
        , Term = 'T3'
      ,[CENSUS_TYPE]
      ,c.[ORG_UNIT_NO]
      ,[VIEW_TYPE]
      ,[COUNT_GROUP]
      ,[COUNT_TYPE]
      ,[AGE_CODE]
      ,[YEAR_LEVEL_CODE] 
      ,[BOY_COUNT]
      ,[GIRL_COUNT]
      ,[TOTAL_COUNT]
      ,[BOY_FTE]
      ,[GIRL_FTE]
      ,[TOTAL_FTE]
      ,School_Type = (case when s.SUBTYPE_NAME in ('Aboriginal Schools','Anangu Schools') then 'Aboriginal/Anangu Schools'
                            else s.SUBTYPE_NAME
                        end)

  FROM c
  LEFT JOIN s
   ON c.ORG_UNIT_NO = s.ORG_UNIT_NO
 -- left join [BI_3].[Rel].[site_decode] as s
    --on convert(int, c.ORG_UNIT_NO) = s.ID
  where CENSUS_YEAR >= 2013
    and CENSUS_TYPE = 'MID'
    and VIEW_TYPE = 'ST'
    and COUNT_TYPE = 'TT'
    and COUNT_GROUP = 'DISABILITIES'
    and s.SUBTYPE_CODE in ('ABSCH','ANSCH','ALTPS','ALTSC','AREA','HIGH','JPS','LANGS','OPACC','PS','SPPRM','PSS','SPPS','SPSEC')

)

--insert the above FTE data into the newly created reporting table

INSERT INTO a
( [Census_Year]
     ,[School_Type]
     ,[FTE]

     )
select Census_Year = ('Yr_' + sp.Census_Year_Convert)
        ,sp.School_Type
        ,FTE = sum(sp.TOTAL_FTE)
from sp
group by sp.Census_Year_Convert

        ,sp.School_Type
order by sp.Census_Year_Convert
        ,sp.School_Type

;
--print 100 if it is sucessful, or -100 if it fails

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    SET @RC = 100;
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @RC = -100;
  END CATCH
  RETURN @RC;
 END
 ;
```

```
ALTER procedure view

as

drop view if exists a

declare @Cols nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @RC int

set @Cols = STUFF((SELECT ', ' +  Census_Year
                FROM b
                --where Census_Year >= 2009
                group by Census_Year
                order by Census_Year
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


                print @Cols

set @Sql = ' 

        create view  a as 
        select School_Type, ' + @Cols +'

        from

        (select School_Type, Census_Year, FTE
        from b

        ) as enr


        pivot (  sum(FTE) for Census_Year in (' + @Cols + ')
                
              ) as pvt

        '

execute(@Sql)
SET @RC = 100
Return @RC
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? There's a lot of recent additions that make things easier, like `STRING_AGG` for building column-lists. Also, please **consistently format and indent** your SQL.

Comment: If you want to just have digits in column names, or any other reserved words for that matter, have you considered wrapping them in `[` and `]` characters by way of the `quotename()` function? Note: This would imply separate variables for your column names and the values in the `in` list.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64)

Comment: Yes i know the indentation is horrible. None of this is my work. im just fixing this train wreck ive been given

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line to add the [] fixed it, thanks for the help :)

```
set @Cols = STUFF((SELECT ',[' +  Census_Year + ']'
```

Comment: `quotename` is a little more resilient for this purpose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 sounds like you are bang in the middle of a huge frustrating mess. Don't let them make you work unpaid overtime for someone elses technical debt... learn what technical debt means and use this term at every opportunity!